# sed replace text - escape characters

Tags: linux, sed, replace, escaping, search-and-replace

I have a mysqldump file in which I want to replace the following text `<a href="/tag/` with `<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/tag/` but can't find a way to correctly escape all special characters.

I'm using the following command (+ a few other variants)
`cat wordpress_posts.sql | sed 's%/<a href="\/\tag\/\/<a href="\http:/\/\www.mydomain.com/\tag/\/%g' > wordpress_posts_new.sql`
but it's not working.

Can anybody help?

Update 1:
Turns out that the source string in the mysqldump isn't `<a href="/tag/` but `<a href=\"/tag/` (note the extra backslash after the equal symbol)
Here's a pastebin of one line of the SQL file which contains the string I want to replace: http://pastebin.com/8G5mcxpJ

I tried all 3 suggested versions of the sed command, but none would replace the above string with `<a href=\"http://www.mydomain.com/tag/`
(yes I added the backslash after the equal symbol)

Comment: All of the answers below work with the data as specified in your question. In your real data there is an additional `\\` that needs to be dealt with. GIGO !

Comment: Have you checked my Update, 50 minutes ago...?

Comment: It doesn't matter really - non of the answers have been updated since, they all work with your original data.

Comment: quanta answered 19 minutes ago with a working answer based on my updated question, which worked. Thus I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to pipe `cat` to `sed`:

`$ sed 's/<a href="\/tag\//<a href="http:\/\/www.mydomain.com\/tag\//g' wordpress_posts.sql`

- Remove the percentage sign
- You only need to escape the slash
- Specify an in-place editing (`-i`) if you want

Comment: This gives me an `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unterminated `s' command` error.

Comment: Are you sure you specify enough 3 delimiters `'s/pattern/replacement/g'`?

Comment: Well I simply copy-pasted your command and changed www.mydomain.com to my own domain, so I suppose it should have worked. I updated my initial post and have added a pastebin link with a line of the sql file containing the string I want to replace.

Comment: Escape the additional backslash with a backslash `sed 's/<a href=\\"\/tag\//<a href=\\"http:\/\/www.mydomain.com\/tag\//g' wordpress_posts.sql`.

Comment: Yeap now it worked :)

Comment: technically the fullstops in your domain also need to be escaped. "." is "any character" in a regex. But I doubt it would affect the outcome in this case.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to escape `/`, you can just use any other delimiter:

```
sed 's#<a href=\\"/tag/#<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/tag/#' wordpress_posts.sql
```

Comment: I hoped that this would work but it didn't :( original and new file have the same size, plus with a grep I can still see instances of `<a href="/tag/`.

Comment: If this pattern occurs several times per line, you have to add a `g` at the end, like `sed '#foo#bar#g' myFile`

Comment: Tried that too, but no. I updated the post with a link to a pastebin containing one line of the sql dump which contains the string I want to replace.

Comment: The backslash at `href=\"/tag/` was missing, I updated my answer.

Comment: People should really use other delimiters, as you've pointed out. "Picket fences" cause confusion and more often lead to syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat wordpress_posts.sql | sed 's/\/tag\//http:\/\/www.mydomain.com\/tag\//' > wordpress_posts.sql
```

Comment: Tried that too, but it didn't work :( I've added a link to a pastebin with the string I want to find and replace to my initial post (Update 1). Maybe this will help..